# Lost one AirPod Pro — but “find my“ thinks it is together with the other one!

Tags: bluetooth, find-my-iphone, airpods

I lost one AirPod pro in my house. However, even though the other AirPod is in its charging case, when I ping them on “find my”, only the one I have makes a sound. See screenshot.

When I click on “right” , see screenshot, (not sure it is even clickable) — nothing happens. Unlikely that the battery is dead since this just happened recently.

Any suggestions would be appreciated! I could “forget” the earbuds and then reconnect them in Bluetooth and try again, but not sure if that’sa good idea...

[image]

Comment: Can you see the AirPod in the Batteries widget? If you are connected to the right AirPod, the battery status will show there.

Comment: Now only one shows up in the widget. Still no sign of the other one. On the “find my” map they appear together though.

Answer (score 1):

> If your AirPods or AirPods Pro are separated from each other, you see
> only one location at a time on the map. Find the AirPod or AirPod Pro
> that you see on the map and put it in its case. Then refresh the map
> and find the other one.

> If your AirPods, AirPods Pro, or AirPods Max are out of range or need
> to charge, you might see their last known location, "No location
> found," or "Offline." You also won't see the location for your AirPods
> or AirPods Pro if they're inside their Charging Case.

> If you see "No location found" or "Offline" under your AirPods,
> AirPods Pro, or AirPods Max, you can't play a sound to find them but
> you might be able to get directions to the location where they were
> last connected. If they do come back online, you'll get a notification
> on the iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch you use them with.

(from [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207581))

Comment: Tx! They are separated! But they appear on the map as if they are together. That’s what baffles me and why I reached  out to this community!

Comment: Based on Apple's support documentation, it is expected behavior to only see one location at a time on the map. The icon on the map shows two AirPod Pros together, but this is just for visualization purposes. If you put one AirPod Pro in the case then refresh the map, it should only display the location of the other AirPod Pro that is not in the case as long as it has power and can be detected.

Comment: Oh damn. Maybe it can’t be detected then. Shoot